# SAS, only a selection of the total number of observations are included in the final dataset. How can I include all observations?

Tags: sas, output

I have written the following program in SAS. The program does what it is supposed to do, but in my final dataset, only 25% of my total observations are included. The program only seems to select a limited number of observations for data processing from the original dataset. How can I adjust the program so that all observations are included and not only the observations in which adjustments have been made by the program? I have tried: `if else output;`  at the end of the program, but this does not seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Program:

```
    set have;
    if variable1 = "information";
    data_format = find(Variable2,'1:');
    data_format2 = find(Variable2,'2:');
    if data_format2 > 0 then do;
        weight_start = find(Variable2,'Weight:');
        weight_end = find(Variable2,'Lengte');
        weight = strip(substr(Variable2,(weight_start+8),(weight_end-8)-weight_start));
    end;
    else if data_format = 0 and find(Variable2,'T=na') > 0 then do;
        weight_start = find(Variable2,'Weight:');
        weight_end = find(Variable2,'Lengte');
        weight = strip(substr(Variable2,(weight_start+8),(weight_end-8)-weight_start));
    end;
    else if data_format = 0 and find(Variable2,'T=na') = 0 then do;
        weight_start = find(Variable2,'Weight:');
        weight_end = find(Variable2,'Lengte');
        weight = strip(substr(Variable2,(weight_start+8),(weight_end-8)-weight_start));
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Give us some data to work with!

Comment: You have a statement immediately have the SET that is supposed to eliminate observations.  Are you saying OTHER observations are being eliminated?

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a subsetting IF statement

```
if variable1 = "information";
```

so only these observations are kept. Maybe you need to use an `if ... then do; ... end;` instead. Something like:

```
set have;
if variable1 = "information" then do;
    data_format = find(Variable2,'1:');
    data_format2 = find(Variable2,'2:');
    if data_format2 > 0 then do;
        weight_start = find(Variable2,'Weight:');
        weight_end = find(Variable2,'Lengte');
        weight = strip(substr(Variable2,(weight_start+8),(weight_end-8)-weight_start));
    end;
    else if data_format = 0 and find(Variable2,'T=na') > 0 then do;
        weight_start = find(Variable2,'Weight:');
        weight_end = find(Variable2,'Lengte');
        weight = strip(substr(Variable2,(weight_start+8),(weight_end-8)-weight_start));
    end;
    else if data_format = 0 and find(Variable2,'T=na') = 0 then do;
        weight_start = find(Variable2,'Weight:');
        weight_end = find(Variable2,'Lengte');
        weight = strip(substr(Variable2,(weight_start+8),(weight_end-8)-weight_start));
    end;
end;
run;
```

Comment: I have used if... then do; ... end; --> This worked! Thanks alot!